# Mongoid update with Positonal operator not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, positional-operator

I am trying to update the mongodb embedded collection using the [$ positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator) from ruby mongoid, but it is not working. Below the mongoid query

```
Viewcounter.collection.update({:item_id=>BSON::ObjectId('yyyy'),'viewinfos.remote_ip' => 'xxxx'},{'$inc' => {'viewinfos.$.viewcount' => 1}})
```

After some more digging i found that no mongodb queries works with mongoid update.including below simple query

```
Item.collection.update({'_id' =>BSON::ObjectId('sss')},{:isused => false})
```

has anyone got a better way of doing the positional operator queries with mongoid?

**EDIT**

But as per the [mongodb official ruby driver documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html#Updating_a_Document), this should work. below the excerpt

```
coll.update({"_id" => doc["_id"]}, {"$set" => {"name" => "MongoDB Ruby"}})
```

Comment: No love? Hope that worked for you.

Answer (score 4):

The general idea is you would drop down to the ruby driver (through the collection) and do it like this:

```
Viewcounter.collection.update({"viewinfos.remote_ip" => "xxxx"}, {:$inc => {"viewinfos.$.viewcount" => 1}})
```

Comment: Your approach was fine. But is there any other way to include the parent id along with $ positional operator. because i need to update a embedded coll based on both parent id and the embedded field..

Comment: You can throw extra conditionals in the query document that select the parent you want. (i think that is what you are asking about) Otherwise you might need to do it on the client side programmatically.